# Will Twilio Trial Account send an actual message?

Tags: java, testing, twilio, account

I am trying to verify [Twilio integration of my Java](https://www.twilio.com/docs/java/install) app, at the moment I am using a trial version, and I am trying to verify that my App is able to send messages to the mentioned numbers, right now I am in India so the "TO" number is a Indian number, but the Trial number "FROM" number is a US number. I see that the messages are logged in Twilio Website, but I haven't received them on my Indian number. Smells bad? or its normal with Trail Account?

The problem is since I haven't been able to see messages in my phone, I am not sure should I go for the paid one - please help.

In addition, when i tried to verify my Indian mobile number I didn't the verification Code as SMS, so I tried the "Call Option" which worked for me.

Thanks and Regards,
Boolean

Answer (score 3):

**Twilio Trial accounts can send messages to verified numbers only.**
I just set one up yesterday and was able to receive the messages while using my Trial.
You can check which numbers are 'validated' for testing purpose by clicking the 'Numbers' tab, and then 'Verified Caller IDs'.

When logged into your Twilio account, click on 'Logs', then 'Messages' and you will get a list of all incoming and outgoing messages that Twilio has processed.

The messages may be being blocked because of Geographic restrictions.  You can check on current geographic permissions and enable as necessary by clicking:

Top right - your email/profile pic.  Then 'Account Settings'.
This will bring up account settings page, as well as a tab of options at the top.  Select 'Geographic Permissions' and make changes as necessary.

Comment: Thanks Mir. 1. Geographic settings - all countries enabled by default. 2. Logs says, my messages have been sent. 3. My "TO" number is already verified by Twilio. I tried verifying another Indian number, for some reason, I don't receive the verification SMS, but "Verifcation by calling" works for verifying the number, but no luck with receiving a single SMS .

Comment: I suspect your carrier is blocking international texts.  I would contact them and ask if you can receive texts from the US, and also what the cost is.  If you found my answer useful please upvote and accept. :)

Comment: Thanks Mir - after having couple of chats with Twilio support - I realized that Twilio won't work for me at the moment - because all Twilio SMS are marked as "PROMOTIONAL" category in India (at the moment). So if one has registered in "Do Not Call" registery maintained by Indian Govt, then he/she will not recive any promotional SMSs. But what I need is "TRANSACTIONAL" SMSs. At the moment Twilio doesn't support TRANSACTIONAL SMSs in India. So I have decided to use a local provider.

Comment: @Boolean You should post that comment as the answer.

Comment: The question was:  Will Twilio Trial Account send an actual message?
Answer: Yes.