# Can't receive SMS through Twilio trial account in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twilio

I'm trying to implement ***phone number verification*** in my app and I've decided to go with [***twilio-ruby***](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby) after dumping [***prove-ruby***](https://github.com/getprove/prove-ruby).

I created an account on ***twilio.com***, verified my mobile number(***India***) to receive SMS, a phone number(***US*** number which has given by Twilio) to send SMS and set up twilio in my app properly. Below is my code

```
#config/initializers/twilio.rb
path = File.join(Rails.root, "config/twilio.yml")
TWILIO_CONFIG = YAML.load(File.read(path))[Rails.env] || {'sid' => '', 'from' => '', 'token' => ''}

#users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    render text: "Thank you! You will receive an SMS shortly with verification instructions."

    # Instantiate a Twilio client
    client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(TWILIO_CONFIG['sid'], TWILIO_CONFIG['token'])

    # Create and send an SMS message
    client.messages.create(
      from: TWILIO_CONFIG['from'],
      to: @user.phone,
      body: "Thanks for signing up. To verify your account, please reply HELLO to this message."
    )
  else
    render :new
  end
end

private
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :phone)
end
end

#new.html.erb
<h1>User Registration</h1>

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <ul>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>

  <p><%= f.label :name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name%></p>

  <p><%= f.label :email %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :email%></p>

  <p><%= f.label :phone %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :phone%></p>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is I can't receive SMS on my mobile. Below is the screen-shot of the ***logs*** on my ***twilio account***.

[image]

According to [***this***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23845957/will-twilio-trial-account-send-an-actual-message) post(see comments), it seems all Twilio SMS are marked as ***PROMOTIONAL*** category in India (at the moment). So if one has registered in ***Do Not Call*** registry maintained by Indian Govt, then he/she will not receive any promotional SMSs.

It makes sense as I activated ***DND(Do Not Disturb)*** on my mobile number long back which blocks any promotional SMSs coming to my mobile.

If that's the case I also tried another mobile number(***which don't have DND activated***), verified it but I don't get any message on it too.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. Don't have an exact answer for you, but I'd take a look at https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/are-there-limitations-on-sending-sms-messages-to-indian-mobile-devices. Looks like your timestamps are before 9pm local India time. Maybe confirm the DND registry? If that resource doesn't prove helpful I'd reach out to the Twilio support team https://www.twilio.com/user/account/support/ticket/create. Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Comment: @eddiezane. Thanks for your time. It makes sense now. I just sent a message to the other number and its got delivered. You can post your comment as an answer :)

Comment: @eddiezane One more thing. I'm developing an app where a user verify his/her phone number by entering a 6 digit PIN received through SMS by twilio. My question is each phone number should be verified before sending/receiving SMSs?

Comment: Yup it's best practice to verify each phone number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This resource might be of use https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/are-there-limitations-on-sending-sms-messages-to-indian-mobile-devices.

Looks like your timestamps are before 9pm local India time. Maybe confirm the DND registry? If that resource doesn't prove helpful I'd reach out to the Twilio support team https://www.twilio.com/user/account/support/ticket/create.