# Sending Twilio SMS from a trial account

Tags: c#, twilio

I am using Twilio and RestSharp packages from nuget to call Twilio using test credentials.  I've verified my personal cell phone already.  I tried using the phone number provided by Twilio as the from number, but I received error [21606](https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21606) saying that I couldn't use a live number with test credentials.  The error description provides another number that can be used with test credentials (+15005550006), so I released the live number and switched to using the one provided.

I can now get a successful response from the service, but the status of all messages I send comes back as `queued`.  The response contains a Uri, but, if I visit the Uri, I get a 403:

```
<TwilioResponse>
  <RestException>
    <Code>20008</Code>
    <Message>Resource not accessible with Test Account Credentials</Message>
    <MoreInfo>https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20008</MoreInfo>
    <Status>403</Status>
  </RestException>
</TwilioResponse>
```

Tracking through that code tells me that I can't [connect to real phone numbers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials).  So, my question is thus:  How do I test the Twilio platform before committing any money to it?  I've seen another question where an answerer has said that [trial accounts can send SMS messages to verified numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23850892/128217), and my Geographic Permissions allow me to send to a +1 number, which the verified number is.  None of the messages I send ever making into my message log.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.  I'm trying to evaluate this to see if my company should use it, but the trial doesn't seem to be enough to give me any indication of usefulness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you still have a trial account (ie you haven't upgraded yet) then you can send real SMS messages to any number that you have verified with Twilio using your production credentials. It won't cost you anything until you upgrade your account.

Test credentials are really there to ensure you can test against certain expected results, both success and more importantly failure cases.

So, just use your real credentials and you will be able to send an SMS to your verified numbers.

Comment: This is incredibly simple and I can't believe I missed it.  However, I switched to the live number and credentials, and now I get 21606 errors back using both the live number (that I just pulled) and the test number mentioned in the question.  The live number is enabled for Voice, SMS, and MMS, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: You need to make sure you're using the number you have bought from Twilio as your From number, a number you have verified with Twilio as your To number and the live credentials. Make sure you've restarted your server too (that always gets me). If you have all that in place, then maybe something else is going wrong.

Comment: I was missing the 1 at the beginning of the From number.  Thanks!  I just got my first text!

Comment: Aaaah! Awesome it works! Feel free to drop me a line on philnash@twilio.com if you want to chat through any other bits at all.